# Add One / +1 to SQLite Record Using Loop

Tags: python, sqlite, loops

I'm working on an app that posts to Twitter and tracks the history in a SQLite3 database using Python.

I'm trying to add one to a field called 'countoftweets' every time the Tweet posts successfully. The Tweet posts successfully and I don't get any errors on the script, but the +1 isn't working correctly.

Full Python loop:

```
if len(tweet_text) <= (280-6):
    try:    
        twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
        twitter.update_status(status=tweet_text)
        cursor.execute("UPDATE quotebot SET countoftweets = countoftweets + 1 WHERE id=?", (quote_id,))
        print("Tweet posted successfully.")
    except TwythonError as error:
            print(error)      
else:
    print('\n'"Tweet too long. Please try again.")
```

The specific line that isn't working correctly (nothing happens, the database value stays at 0):

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE quotebot SET countoftweets = countoftweets + 1 WHERE id=?", (quote_id,))
```

Any idea why the value stays at zero and what I could change here to make it actually do a +1 every time it runs? Thanks!

Comment: Do you ever call `commit()` on the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Per a suggestion from @snakecharmerb, I added this and it now works:

```
sqliteConnection.commit()
```

Final working code block:

```
if len(tweet_text) <= (280-6):
    try:    
        twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
        twitter.update_status(status=tweet_text)
        cursor.execute("UPDATE quotebot SET countoftweets = countoftweets + 1 WHERE id=?", (quote_id,))
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Tweet posted successfully.")
    except TwythonError as error:
            print(error)      
else:
    print('\n'"Tweet too long. Please try again.")
```